# jquery hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get same effect like this

http://bavotasan.com/demos/fadehover/

But only for anchor tags not for images, let say I have anchor background blue and I want it to change to red but with this effect, how can I do that? thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `hover` and `animate`. Note that this requires the jQuery color animations plugin.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>color change</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.color.js.txt" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {
      $('a').hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({
          color: "#f00"
        }, "fast")
      }, function() {
        $(this).animate({
          color: "#00f"
        }, "fast")
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    a { color: #00f; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#">This changes color on hover.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

In the example of changing color on an `a` element there is no reason to use the crossfade effect used in the link you provide.

Answer (score 3):

Placing two images on top of eachother (via CSS: *position* and *z-index*). A black and white one, and a color one:

```
/* Assumes width and height are the same between all three elements */
.viewBox  { position:relative; width:125px; height:125px; display:block; }
img.color { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:10; }
img.bandw { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; }

<a class="viewBox" href="http://google.com">
  <img src="color.jpg" class="color" />
  <img src="bandw.jpg" class="bandw" />
</a>

$(".viewBox").hover(
  function() {
    $("img.color").fadeIn();
  },
  function() {
    $("img.color").fadeOut();
  }
);
```

--

Alternatively, you can accomplish this without jQuery, using pure css too:

```
span.hov span            { display:none; }
.rollover                { display:block; background-image:url('bandw.jpg'); 
                           width:125px; height:125px; }
.rollover span.hov       { display:none;  background-image:url('color.jpg');
                           width:125px; height:125px; }
.rollover:hover span.hov { display:block; }

<a class="rollover">
  <span class="hov">
    <span>Invisible Link Text</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: My question is how can do it with <a> tags , and you are opening <div> and closing </a> .. tnx

Answer (score 0):

The HTML, CSS and jQuery is available on the web page for you.

Here, the creator has layed 2 images on top of each other then uses jQuery to change the opacity.

```
<div class="fadehover">
  <img class="a" alt="" src="cbavota-bw.jpg" style="opacity: 1;"/>
  <img class="b" alt="" src="cbavota.jpg"/>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".a").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
  });
});
```